# Code runs well, but stuck in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

Let me preface by saying I am not highly knowledgeable in this context.  I found some code online and tailored it to my needs.  When I run it, it does what I want it to do (delete a row the contains one value in column K and one value in column J), but it will continually run without end. When I cancel it, it has completed the task at hand, so I assume it is just stuck in a loop.  Any and all help would be great.

"If Not rFind Is Nothing Then" is the line that is highlighted when the code Debugs.

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Dim rFind As Range
    Dim rFind2 As Range
    Dim rDelete As Range
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim iLookAt As Long
    Dim bMatchCase As Boolean

    strSearch = Range("AJ1")
    strSearch2 = Range("AK1")

    iLookAt = xlWhole
    bMatchCase = False

    Set rDelete = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheet1.Columns("J:J")
        Set rFind2 = .Find(strSearch2, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=iLookAt, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=bMatchCase)
        If Not rFind2 Is Nothing Then
            Do
                With Sheet1.Columns("K:K")
                    Set rFind = .Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=iLookAt, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=bMatchCase)
                    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
                        Do
                            Set rDelete = rFind
                            Set rFind = .FindPrevious(rFind)
                            If rFind.Address = rDelete.Address Then Set rFind = Nothing
                            rDelete.EntireRow.Delete
                        Loop While Not rFind Is Nothing
                    End If
                End With
            Loop While Not rFind2 Is Nothing
        End If
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your outer loop

```
Loop While Not rFind2 Is Nothing
```

will continue to loop, as nothing ever sets rFind2 to Nothing. It looks as though you want to clear it in the same place as rFind:

```
 If rFind.Address = rDelete.Address Then
     Set rFind = Nothing
     Set rFind2 = Nothing
 End If
```

Comment: Okay, so this gives me an error, saying I have a Loop without and End, and the code is not working how I want, it deletes a row if column K contains the specified value, and does NOT delete it if column K and column J both contain their specified values.